# wowza apple hls event tracking

Tags: wowza, http-live-streaming

hi i am using wowza streaming engine 4 , to stream smil file 
i am able to trace events when file play on flash, 
and gether informantions like , which file play , time etc, 
in onConnect() event,
precisely i want to get which file is played  from my smil file. 
but in case of apple hls streaming when i try to get file name in onHTTPSessionDestroy() method , eg.

```
    public void onHTTPSessionDestroy(IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession) {
            String streamName = httpSession.getStreamName();
}
```

i only get the name of smil file , not the actual file played .

is it possible to get the played file info in wowza hls steaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Api is introduce in wowza 4.1.1

```
public void onHTTPStreamerRequest(IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession, IHTTPStreamerRequestContext reqContext)
```

we can get check which bit-rate is played like media_w1577403587_b4000000_1.ts
_b is the bitrate